# How to use 'armcc' compiler to trace function calls?

Tags: gcc, arm, trace, armcc

I used to use **gcc** `-fdump-rtl-expand` and `-finstrument-functions` to do function call tracing, does **armcc** has this kind of similar function?

For **gcc**, I use:

```
CFLAGS += -finstrument-functions -fdump-rtl-expand
```

Does **armcc** have similar compiler options? I tried the same ones, but it seems they do not work:

```
$ armcc -finstrument-functions test.c
Fatal error: C3900U: Unrecognized option '-finstrument-functions'.
$ armcc -fdump-rtl-expand test.c
Fatal error: C3900U: Unrecognized option '-fdump-rtl-expand'.
```

Comment: yes, I tried, no these two option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the option which allows `gcc` style instrumentation with `armcc` is different.

Here is an extract from *ARM Compiler Toolchain: Compiler Reference* (You can access the reference at http://infocenter.arm.com, if you 'register' on their website):

> `--gnu_instrument, --no_gnu_instrument`
>
> This option inserts GCC-style instrumentation calls for profiling
>   entry and exit to functions.
>
> **Usage**
>
> After function entry and before function exit, the following profiling
>   functions are called with the address of the current function and its
>   call site:
>
> void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void *current_func, void *callsite);
>
> void __cyg_profile_func_exit(void *current_func, void *callsite);
>
> **Restrictions**
>
> You must provide definitions of __cyg_profile_func_enter() and
>   __cyg_profile_func_exit().
>
> It is necessary to explicitly mark `__cyg_profile_func_enter()` and
>   `__cyg_profile_func_exit()` with `__attribute__((no_instrument_function))`.
>
> **See also**
>
> `__attribute__((no_instrument_function))` function attribute.

As to the `-fdump-rtl-expand` option: I do not know (and do not think) that `armcc` uses RTL internally. So I do not think obtaining the logs from the *expand* pass makes any sense here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think instrument may use for dynamic tracing the function call, and I use `-fdump-rtl-expand` for **gcc** to do the static trace, does **ARM** has this kind of `fdump` like function?

Comment: I don't know. You could look in the manual and search for one. I'm curious: Any reason why you prefer `armcc` over `gcc` for ARM?

Comment: company dicision...:( anyway thanks for your help, btw, do you mind provide me an `arm-linux-gcc` toolchain download link?

Comment: There's *crosstool-ng* that helps you build one for yourself, and then there is *CodeSourcery/MentorGraphics'* pre-built ARM toolchain. Probably a load of others too.